# Is it possible to make a higher order function over a typeguard?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I have the following fairly basic function:

```
function isNil<T>(x: T | undefined | null): x is undefined | null {
  return x === undefined || x === null;
}
```

This works fairly well to infer that `x` is definitely a typesafe. However, I want to create a higher order function which will be able to *invert* this operation. Here's my basic implementation so far:

```
function complement<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>(fn: T) {
  return (...args: Parameters<T>) => !fn(...args);
}
```

This allows me to make a function like this:

```
const isNotNil = complement(isNil);
```

However, it infers the type slightly strangely:

```
const isNotNil: (x: unknown) => boolean
```

This appears to remove the typeguard:

[image]

Is there a way in typescript to achieve this?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgGwKau2KAHgBVFsAPKfAEwGdEAKAOheDAEEAnAc1oC5E4ANZg4AdzABtALoBKRAF4AfILAjxYJQzYDi8gN4AoRCcSdsUEJyTMWAQx79EABQd28VTrRJL5yxACEbLZMDryyANyGAL6GhqCQsAiIMLQAcjCYPgzkuogAPohgIJiYBarU2MAwYNjUsgLkKfTgldW11OXFpYhGpmYWVkhNCqNFJWX5hSNjrVU1dVGxhihgtFDNaXBQGWUKyGhYuPhQDKm7kXGr64jUdlB2ioiSAOR2LwA0iC8ARp-jpS+c3adWkUUMdweTGqmE8Z3S2wuTFQdnQZyoqEUKhgGKYUDgAFV0OhsJwAMJ2WjYBiySJAA)

Comment: _it cannot infer that it should be not null or not undefined_ Can you elaborate what shouldn't be null or not undefined? Example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play would be helpful

Comment: it correctly infers to use `x` as a single argument, but puts its type to `unknown`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgGwKau2KAHgBVFsAPKfAEwGdEAKAOheDAEEAnAc1oC5E4ANZg4AdzABtALoBKRAF4AfILAjxYJQzYDi8gN4AoRCcSdsUEJyTMWAQx79EABQd28VTrRJL5yxACEbLZMDryyANyGAL6GhqCQsAiIMLQAcjCYPgzkuogAPohgIJiYBarU2MAwYNjUsgLkKfTgldW11OXFpYhGpmYWVkhNCqNFJWX5hSNjrVU1dVGxhihgtFDNaXBQGWUKyGhYuPhQDKm7kUA

Comment: Ah, no, the guard won't be carried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, TypeScript won't automatically infer a predicate type as a function return this way.  You can manually annotate your `complement()` function so as to behave possibly reasonably in some circumstances, but it's somewhat brittle:

- Type guard function signatures can guard any of their arguments, like `(x: any, y: any) => x is string` guards the first argument, and `(x: any, y: any) => y is string` guards the second one.   There is not, as far as I know, a way to programmatically identify a type guard function for all possible locations of the guarded parameter.  In what follows I will assume that we only care about type guard functions where the *first* parameter is guarded.
- TypeScript does not currently support *negated types* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) for an experiment to support them) which would let you take `x is T` and turn it into `x is not T`.  Without a suitable *`not`* type operator, we need to make do with such utility types as [`Exclude<X, T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) which only behave properly to pull members out of union types.  This will work for your use case (`Exclude<T | null | undefined, T>` will be `null | undefined`), but will fail for many others (e.g., `Exclude<string, "a">` is just `string`; there is no all-`string`s-except-`"a"` type).

---

That said, here it is:

```
function complement<T, A extends any[], U extends T>(
  fn: (x: T, ...args: A) => x is U): (x: T, ...args: A) => x is Exclude<T, U>;
function complement<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R): (...args: A) => boolean;
function complement(fn: Function) {
  return (...args: any) => !fn(...args);
}
```

I've added the type-guard-processing signature as an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).  If a function you pass in doesn't match that signature it should try the second, more general overload, which will just return a `boolean`-returning thing.

---

All right, let's try it:

```
function isNil<T>(x: T | undefined | null): x is undefined | null {
  return x === undefined || x === null;
}

const isNotNil = complement(isNil);
//const isNotNil: <T>(x: T | null | undefined) => x is Exclude<T, null | undefined>

const foo = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : null;

if (isNotNil(foo)) {
  console.log(foo.toUpperCase()); // HELLO if we reach here
}
```

Hey, it works.  `isNotNil`'s type signature is automatically the right generic function type due to the support for [higher order function type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) introduced in TypeScript 3.4.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: that's amazing! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you end up mixing the "is" and the the actual boolean test
Why not simply separate out the actual boolean check and use that?

Here are two different examples that might help:

```
type Nil = undefined | null;
const nil = (v: unknown) => v === null || v === undefined;


const isNil = <T,>(x: T | Nil): x is Nil => nil(x);
const isNotNil = <T,>(x: T | Nil): x is T => !nil(x);

const data = ['a', 'b', null, undefined];

const a = data.filter(isNil);
const b = data.filter(isNotNil);

// Create both checks based on one function
const checks = <V,U>(isV: (x: U | V) => boolean) => {
    return {
        is: (x: U | V): x is V => isV(x),
        isNot: (x: U | V): x is U => !isV(x),
    }
}

const {is, isNot} = checks<string, Nil>(nil);

const c = data.filter(is);
const d = data.filter(isNot);

data.filter(isNotNil).map(item => item.toUpperCase());
```